# Is there a complete list of types produced by Mule inbound endpoints?

Tags: mule

We purchased an Enterprise Mule license in May, and I have also bought and read your [Mule in Action](http://www.manning.com/dossot/) at Manning.com. I read Enterprise Integration Patterns, and I have used Mule doc extensively -- I cannot seem to find a comprehensive list of what endpoints produce what kind of data types, or what properties are available for that specific message at any one stage of a flow.

Example: I used a JDBC endpoint to read from a mySQL database and received back a list of maps. Yet i don't see a Mule object to process this list of maps, so i had to write a component in Java to process it and return the columns i wanted from the result set.

I stumbled in the dark thru this whole process, and I am not a rookie in Java EE; I have been using Java and WebSphere off and on for 10 years.

I had read the Mule and MVEL docs and all I see are the Mule object/context names, but no more about when and how they will be available or what data format they will return in.

Is there a comprehensive list of what endpoints (or any other Mule object(s)) produce what kind of data types and also what properties are available for that specific message at any one stage of a flow?

Comment: Hopefull you bought the Second Edition of Mule in Action: http://manning.com/dossot2/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Mule reference guide still lacks a formal definition of the generated payload types and supported properties (inbound end endpoint). MuleSoft is aware of the lack and has started to document the latter, as you can see for the [HTTP transport](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference#HTTPTransportReference-HTTPProperties).

For now your best bet is to use visual breakpoints in Studio or `<logger>` elements to introspect the message characteristics.

Comment: Thanks David, I appreciate the advice and your frank appraisal regarding the lack of formal definition and cross reference of Mule Objects/payload detail/Properties available etc. The HTTP transport reference was a step in the right direction. We just need it a tabular xref version, one place for all info. And yes, I have been following the Manning EAP bulletins of the Mule in Action second edition with great interest :-) Is it all completed now? Thanks for your great leadership in the Mule Arena!

Comment: You're welcome. I wish I had a better answer to give. And yes, the book is coming to an end: we've entered the "polishing" phase :)

Comment: David, I just got my electronic copy of Mule in Action 2nd Edition - great stuff, really enjoying it, and looking forward to getting my final paper copy!